# KeystoreName of SectionInformation.ProtectSection generated Key

Tags: c#, encryption, web-config

I want to encrypt the web.config of an WebAPI with the method SectionInformation.ProtectSection.

This will generate a default key named "Rsa Key" in the Windows machine-keystore. (Location: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys)
In my encrypted web.config it says Rsa Key

So far so good, I want to assign privileges to the IIS-User with the command:

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "Rsa Key" -full
```

It just fails and tells me the Key-Container does not exist.

How do I find out the name of the key that was generated using the method SectionInformation.ProtectSection?

Comment: Maybe `aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "<IIS-User>"`.

Comment: seems to work thx!